# Objects coming together due to small gravitational attraction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Theoretically, if I place two objects, say, 3 feet apart would they be touching thousands of years later due to the gravitational force, GM/r^2, they exert on each other?

Comment: Is this with friction, or are these objects in a vacuum? Please mark up your math with mathjax, and try to use more descriptive titles for questions.

Answer (score 3):

Consider two bowling balls, each with a mass of 8 kilograms and a radius of 12 centimeters. Start them at rest in space where there is no friction, with their centers 3 feet apart.

Their gravitational attraction will bring them into contact after just 7.74 hours. It doesn't take thousands of years!

This time can be calculated with the formula given here for radial freefall under an inverse square gravitational force:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field

Just substitute 3 feet for $y_0$, 24 centimeters for $y$, and 8 kilograms for $m_1$ and $m_2$.

Answer (score 1):

First, gravitational force is $\frac{GMm}{r^2}$.  Just by analysing this formula, the value of $M$ and $m$ have to be extremely high, given that $G\approx6.67\times10^{-11}m^3kg^{-1}s^{-2}$ and your radius is only about $1m$.

Hence, the force will be so small that it is unable to even overcome frictional forces.  However, let's say if this were to be done in space and assuming no external gravitational forces, it would be possible for them to meet eventually.